# Tricky mysql join

Tags: mysql, join

I'm a little stuck with an sql query. I've searched everywhere but to no avail so was hoping somebody here could help.

I have 2 tables.

Table 1 is a list of notifications with the following columns

- `notification_id` (this is the auto incremented primary key)
- `notification` (This is the notification message)
- `from_id` (This is the user_id of the person sending the notification)

eg.

```
|  notification_id  |  notification  |  from_id  |
|       25          |  this message  |    7      |
|       26          |  that message  |    8      |
```

Table 2 shows which users have read each notification. It has the following columns

- `notification_id` (this is the id of the relevant notification)
- `user_id` (This is the user id of the person who has read the notification)

eg.

```
| notification_id   |   user_id   |
|     25            |      1      |
|     25            |      2      |
|     25            |      3      |
|     26            |      2      |
```

The tables are joined on `notification_id` and we have a one to many relationship as many users will read each notification.

What I am trying to do is query the database to return all the notifications that the particular user has not already read. In other words I want the data from table one but only if table 2 doesn't have an entry where user_id is (My `user_id` x) for the corresponding `notification_id`.

So if my `user_id` is 4 then I get the data for both `notification_id` 25 and 26 as `user_id` 4 is not listed in table 2 for either of those

If my `user_id` is 2 I don't get any data as `user_id` 2 is listed in table 2 as having read both `notification_id` 25 and 26

If my `user_id` is 1 I get the data for `notification_id` 26 but not 25

I originally thought I could use this

```sql
SELECT
    notification_id, notification, from_id 
FROM table_1 
INNER JOIN table 2 
    ON table_1.notification_id = table2.notification_id
WHERE table2.user_id != X
```

But this is actually a long way off what I need and I've reached a bit of a dead end.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do a left join and look for empty joins.

```
SELECT notification_id, notification, from_id FROM table_1
LEFT JOIN table_2 ON table_2.notification_id = table_1.notification_id AND table_2.user_id = x
WHERE table_2.notification_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Works a treat and is nice and efficient. Many thanks to everyone who offered help.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    notification_id, notification, from_id 
FROM table_1 
WHERE 
    notification_id NOT IN (SELECT notification_id from table_2 WHERE user_id = X)
```

Answer (score 0):

first search all notification the user got and than get all others

```
SELECT
    notification_id, notification, from_id 
FROM table_1 
WHERE notification_id not in 
     (SELECT notification_id
      FROM  table 2   
      WHERE table2.user_id == X)
```